# casting a struct in c

Tags: pointers, casting, struct

I need an array of user structs.

```
struct user {
    char *username;
};  

struct user users[10]; //Array of user structs

int main(int argc, char **args) {
    int initUsersArray();        
    char *username = "Max";
    addToUsersArrry(username);

}



int addToUsersArrry(username) {
int i;
i = 0;
struct user tmp;    
for(i;i<10;i++) {
    if(users[i] != NULL) 
        if(strcmp(*users[i].username,username)==0)
            return -1;
}
i = 0;
for(i;i<10;i++) {
    if(users[i] = NULL) { 
        users[i]=tmp;
        users[i].username=username;
        return 1;
    }   

}   

}

int initUsersArray() {  
int i;
i=0;
struct user tmp;

for(i;i<10;i++) {
    users[i] = (struct user*) calloc(1,sizeof(tmp));
}
}
```

My first question is, if it is the right way to init the users array with NULL like i did.
The second problem is, that 
    *users[i].username
and other parts of code where want to get/set the user at a specific position, dont work.
Regards

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: I have updated one line, but rest of code is copied correcty. I am new to c, so dont be suprised if i wrote "strange" code.

Comment: You should use the empty string or '\0' instead of NULL, i.e. "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I fixed it for you. And don't forget to diff and learn something. Don't just c/p it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct user {
    char *username;
} user;

user *users; //Array of user structs

int addToUsersArray(char *username) {
int i = 0;

for(; i<10; i++) {
    if(users[i].username=='\0') {
        users[i].username = username;
    return 1;
    } else if(strcmp(users[i].username, username) == 0)
    return -1;
}
return -1;
}

void initUsersArray() {  
    users = (user*) calloc(10, sizeof(user)); //10 of them
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    initUsersArray();        
        char *username = "Max";
        addToUsersArray(username);
    username = "Ma1x";
    addToUsersArray(username);
    printf("%s\n",users[0].username);
    printf("%s\n",users[1].username); 
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for fixing. Where is the difference in using "." instead of "->"?

Comment: It's just a shorthand (Syntactic sugar) for `*(pointerToSomething).field`

Comment: Ah okey, but does "." has another meaning? And look at your code, i tried to check if username already exists and getting a segmentationfault.

Comment: See my updated answer. I encourage you to go step-by-step through this code and google everything unfamiliar.

Comment: unfamiliar to me was only that if i compare a string with a empty string, that i get a segmentation fault. Thank you very much (hvala ti puno ;))

Comment: Sorry there is still something unfamiliar, why do you use user* users[10] instead of user users[10]?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a rush while changing your code. See my updated answer, I hope it makes things more clear now. Nema problema ;)